# How can we programatically get public key from passphrase protected private key without creating an SSH connection?

Tags: python, ssh, cryptography, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys

I want to use Python to get public key from private key which is passphrase protected. When there is no passphrase we can easily get it by executing **ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub** in bash. But I was not able to find a command or a library which could retrieve the public key from passphrase protected private key , without creating an SSH connection.

Comment: Perhaps [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) is right for you. [This method](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key) seems on point.

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa
```

on a passphrase protected private key, you are asked for the passphrase to the key.

If you can't provide the key via stdin, for example because you are running from a script, the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) lists the `-P` option to `ssh-keygen` that allows you to specify the passphrase in the command. So your command invocation could look like this

```
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa -P <your-passphrase>
```

Comment: Can we provide private key as well in the input instead of file like we did for passphrase in the above command?

Comment: I can't find an option that would do what you want in the man page